# Reading in local sound file with Howler in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, howler.js

I am trying to read in a local .wav file and play it with Howler.

```
var sound = new Howl({
    src: ['doremi.wav']
})
sound.play()
```

And I get an error: http://localhost:3000/doremi.wav
Even though the sound file is in the same directory as the code file. Howler is initiating a get request to my app, but I just want it to read in the local file. Why is it doing a get request?

Thank you.

Comment: Url you've provided won't help as it is localhost, please post exact error

Comment: This likely has something to do with how ReactJS accesses files. I was researching the same issue for Angular and came across this github issue in howler.js repository: https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/1028. At the end of the thread it shows that for Angular, static files should go into the src/assets folder otherwise Angular will not access them.

Answer (score 0):

> Even though the sound file is in the same directory as the code file.

It doesn't matter what directory it's in.  An HTTP request still has to be made.  Without a full URL, what you specify is relative to the current page base URL.  If that's `http://localhost:3000/`, then trying to load `doremi.wav` will load `http://localhost:3000/doremi.wav`.

> but I just want it to read in the local file

The browser doesn't really know or care that `localhost` happens to be a web server running on the same machine.  It's just a hostname like anything else such as `example.com`.  Everything loaded at this URL comes over the web server running on your machine.  Your browser can't load files locally for this page, unless the user were to drag them into the page or put them into a File input.